# How to explain subdomain creation and masking to a semi-noob?

Tags: web-hosting, subdomain, domain-forwarding

**Note:** Excuse my ambguity, as my bosses *are* aware of what I intend to do, but I'm not sure they'll appreciate me asking about it on a public discussion board.

I've tried looking up the existing threads and they don't seem to match my problem.

**Background:** I work at a large corporation, a media company, and this corporation has a website. The problem is, this website sucks and is designed according to standards from the nineties. I was recently tasked with a new "project" within this corporation, and this project needs to have a website. This website will contain details about the project, as well as podcasts which I plan to host at [Libsyn](https://www.libsyn.com/).

I don't want to use the infrastructure (CMS, hosting) of my corporation because they suck and fail from time to time. Therefore, what I want to do is pay for a webhost of my own, install Wordpress, and use it as the site for the project, alongside Libsyn for podcasts.

**The issue, or "thing":** It wouldn't be politically correct for this "project" to be on an entirely different site (domain) than the rest of the corporation. So I've agreed with my bosses that while I will manage and pay for the hosting of all content, the address for this project will be at myproject.mycorporation.com. So it's masked.

I've dealt with domain mapping and subdomains before, up to a certain complexity. I'm pretty sure I **know** what needs to be done, but I don't want to screw the explanation up to the outsourced company my corporation works with to manage its website (they will need to *actualyy* point the subdomain to my server).

How do I explain this procedure to the company? Personally, I use namecheap but I don't know what they're using. What terms do I use to describe what they need to do? Here's what I have in mind:

- I create a self-hosted website at a domain of my own: mydomain.io
- Company needs to create subdomain: myproject.mycorporation.com

Up until here it's all clear, but these are the two steps I'm not sure of:

- Company needs to set A Records of said subdomain to mydoamin.io
- I need to set mydomain.io to redirect to myproject.mycorporation.com

Something feels wrong here? Can anyone list a summary of the steps needed to do this? Please note that my corporatin's website must not be affected.

Comment: Bit of an aside, but... you are working for a "large corporation" and you are _personally_ going to upfront the costs of a project's website for this large corporation. Are you sure? (Are they really OK with that?)

Comment: The corporation is large, the project has my name on it and isn't a "flagship" project right now, I like to get things done. I'm sure I'm OK with the expenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok zerohedge it sounds indeed like you're a little confused. To help clarify, what you are trying to do is setup an independently hosted website running Wordpress and to use a subdomain for this.

Ideally you would follow these steps:

1. Setup website hosting for myproject.mycorporation.com (avoid using a different domain such as mydomain.io), you will not need to purchase a domain name to do this, and don't worry that initially it will not work in a web-browser.
2. Ask whoever manages the mycorporation.com domain name to create a new `A` record for the subdomain *myproject* to point to the IP address assigned to you by the website hosting company.
3. After a period of up to 72 hours it should work in your web-browser as expected. The actual time it takes to update and replicate the DNS records across the Internet depends on the value set for TTL (Time-To-Live) as currently specified in seconds. For example, a TTL of 86400 seconds equates to 1 day. Network Tools provide a DNS records lookup tool which will reveal the current TTL for your domain name's existing A records:
   http://network-tools.com/nslook/Default.asp?domain=example.com&type=1&server=67.222.132.198&class=1&port=53&timeout=5000&go.x=18&go.y=10

Try to avoid using a temporary domain name or 'masking' a different domain name such as mydomain.io to appear as myproject.mycorporation.com (using a `CNAME` record) since this will cause problems later on:

- The website mywebsite.io would still be accessible and could be confusing to users.
- Search engines will treat each website domain independently and since the content will appear the same both domains will suffer a degraded search position or page rank penalty for *duplicate content*.

Comment: Thank you. I may not have a choice since I'll be using wpengine.com. It creates a subdomain automatically but I can easily redirect mywebsite.io → corporation domain name after I set the other to the IP address.